# Dungeon World DM companion app

Tags: tools, dungeon-world, tool-recommendation

I'll be DMing a 10 people group in Dungeon World, so I figured keeping track of everything using pen&paper could be difficult. I'm searching for an app that is specific for Dungeon World, with things like connections between character, selected moves and spells, etc, on top of classic stats like hp, coins, exp, ammo that are more generic.

A huge plus would be a monster tracker, where I'd keep track of monsters' health.

If I can't find a DW specific app, I'd like at least a generic DM companion app to help me.
I'm looking for an Android application.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate here, is there any reason you don't trust the _players_ to keep track of their own Bonds, HP, Gold, XP and ammo? I've never felt the need for any bookkeeping of the player's stats at all in either DW or AW.

Comment: They are mostly noobs, Hp is easy to keep track, but everyone forget ammos, xp, etc.
Also, I like to have an overview of what's happening, to build scenes that work best for the party. Bonds in particular could offer nice cues to advance the plot and needing to ask them could break the surprise.
Again, this can be done with pen & paper, but I'm always for the digital help if it doesn't break the flow.

Comment: Since this is a [tag:tool-recommendation] question I can't really give "don't do your player's book-keeping" as an answer, so I'll just leave this as a comment. Book-keeping as a Dungeon World GM will just distract you from your actual role (as defined by your GM Principles, which are rules just like HP, Stats and Moves) so minimize as much as possible by letting your players do their own, they're only playing one character each, you're playing the entire world. Focus on the world, not the numbers, little mistakes in book-keeping are far less harmful than a slowed down story.

Comment: Just a side note: most of the consumable management has been highly abstracted in DW to simplify book keeping. Attacking with a bow doesn't necessarily deplete an arrow from inventory, for example.

Comment: @Aiken Actually you can and should. As long as your preamble makes it clear what assumptions in the question you're rejecting, and make a good argument for rejecting them, you can make that an answer. In comments it will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of any DW specific app for any platform.  Obsidian Portal, Roll 20, or other online RPG apps might have specific sheets/formats for what you are looking for.  I've never tried them though.

However, when I run DW, I used a spreadsheet during combat.  I have all the data I need in the spreadsheet.

Since I'm on iOS/OSX, I use Numbers, but Excel is available for almost all platforms, and Google Sheets is available as well.

It takes more work to set up the spreadsheet to be game specific, but it will be exactly what you need, rather than what an app believes you need.

For non-combat, I use OneNote.  Other options are Evernote and Google Docs.  Again, the premise that a general purpose tool is fluid enough to match my needs compared to specific tools.  It's simple to jot down notes, especially things I make up on the fly but likely will need to remember as a scenario progresses.

Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Edit note: Apologies as I did not see the android specific part of your question.

Android:
For campaign management unfortunately there is no catch all tool as of yet. Not even one for purchase. However you can make due through multiple tools as I did before I upgraded to a PC tool.

My first suggestion is of course a standard HP/initiative tracker for combat. There are a varied plethora of options ranging from simple HP to HP and effects buffs etc.

So many in fact that covering them all will take all night to write.

For detailed location,rule, NPC, PC and more information I suggest this relatively new app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.maranathatechnologies.gamemasterscompanionpro

The game master companion pro is not system specific. Use it as a tool to note everything from monsters and items to people and places. Even story events. Information can be referenced via links to other templates you've created inside the app for faster cross referencing.

The app is new and does have one bug. It doesn't close previously open pages unless you back out of said page so after being 4-5 pages in depending on your phone it may freeze and crash. You do not lose any saved information thankfully but it can get annoying.

For PC:

If as I did you decide to upgrade to a PC based management system I suggest all go with what I've gotten as option 1.

http://www.wolflair.com/realmworks/

Realm works from a DM standpoint is leagues above everything else in terms of full campaign record keeping.

However this doesn't exactly record xp and the like but managing connections and information and plot points is right up its ally.

Control what your players see by marking lines as player known so they can see it in player view.

Besides this I think the best option would be an excel sheet you create yourself.

There's nothing wrong with wanting all the information at your fingertips in an easy to review format. Not just for keeping track of your players info but also for recording and tracking your own info as well including npc

The company also released a hero lab program for creating characters. This program can be referenced via realm works and also includes useful gmtools for use during gameplay.

Free option would be pcgen. 
While unable to manage full campaign info PC gen is a definitive character creation program with multiple game rulesets and the ability to make your own after learning programming.

It has gm tools available inside for HP init and other combat based tracking. And you can build and reference each persons character sheet.

Comment: Didn't see that part of his question. Though realm works is by far the best option as a pc based tool. I'll be adding an android suggestion soon.